# Excel: Search for a list of strings within a particular string using array formulas?

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, find

I want to search a cell for a list of words.
I thought this would work as an array formula:

```
{=FIND(<list of words I want to search for>,<cell I want to search>)}
```

But it only finds a match when a word that's in the cell I'm searching sits in the first row of the list of words I'm searching for.  Is there any way to write a formula that looks through the entire list?  And I'd prefer if it didn't just return TRUE/FALSE.  I know how to search cell for a list of words and return TRUE/FALSE based on whether or not a word in the list exists in the cell.  I want to actually know which word was found, or its position.

Comment: This would probably be much simpler if you could use multiple ``FIND`` calls:  e.g. use one-cell-per-word-searched. Is that an option? Alternatively, you could write a VBA function to handle this.

Comment: the <list of words I want to search for> is an array with one word per cell.  Is this what you mean?  I don't know VBA, but do you know of any example VBA code that does something similar?

Comment: Could whoever downvoted me please provide some feedback?

Comment: If you don't know VBA, first try doing a ``FIND`` in each cell adjacent to the array of cells you want to search. You'll get one result per word searched and then can use that information however you want.

Comment: oh I see, for each cell I want to search, do a row of FINDs, one per word that I'm searching for.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This will return the matching word or an error if no match is found. For this example I used the following.

List of words to search for: `G1:G7`
Cell to search in: `A1`

```
=INDEX(G1:G7,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(G1:G7,A1)),-1,1)*(ROW(G1:G7)-ROW(G1)+1)))
```

Enter as an array formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This formula works by first looking through the list of words to find matches, then recording the position of the word in the list as a positive value if it is found or as a negative value if it is not found. The largest value from this array is the position of the found word in the list. If no word is found, a negative value is passed into the `INDEX()` function, throwing an error.

To return the row number of a matching word, you can use the following:

```
=MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(G1:G7,A1)),-1,1)*ROW(G1:G7))
```

This also must be entered as an array formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. It will return `-1` if no match is found.

Comment: Just one question: why do you multiply by `(ROW(G1:G7)-ROW(G1)+1)` instead of just `ROW(G1:G7)`?  For my purpose, I want the row of the word found, so I just used `ROW(G1:G7)`.

Comment: That was my way of making the formula more general. The second argument of the `INDEX` function is the relative position in the array, not the fixed row number.  So if your list of search terms started at `G3` instead, using `ROW(G3:G9)` by itself would return an incorrect result.

Comment: I added a formula that will return the row number of the match, since it sounds like you're also interested in that.

Comment: This doesn't work in Excel 2010 since ISERROR has 2 mandatory parameters.

Comment: @dnLL Are you sure about that? Sounds wrong to me. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IS-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665

Comment: @Excellll No you are right, I totally mixed it up with IFERROR for some reason! Thank you.

Comment: Does the list need to be sorted? Somehow not worked for me. Using MS Excel for Mac.

Answer (score 8):

Adding this answer for people like me for whom a TRUE/FALSE answer is perfectly acceptable

```
OR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($G$1:$G$7,A1)),TRUE,FALSE))
```

or case-sensitive

```
OR(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND($G$1:$G$7,A1)),TRUE,FALSE))
```

Where the range for the search terms is `G1:G7`

Remember to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Comment: search is case-INsensitive

Comment: Or simply `=OR(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH({"Word 1","Word 2","Word 3"},MyRange))))`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Arange your word list with delimiter which never occures in the words, f.e. |
2. swap arguments in find call - we want search if cell value is matching one of the words in pattern string
   `{=FIND("cell I want to search","list of words I want to search for")}`
3. if the patterns are similar, there is a risk of getting more results than wanted, we restrict just correct results via adding &"|" to the cell value tested (works well with array formulas)
   cell G3 could contain: `{=SUM(FIND($A$1:$A$100&"|";A3))}`
   this ensures spreadsheet will compare strings like "cellvlaue|" againts "pattern1|", "pattern2|" etc. which sorts out conflicts like pattern1="newly added", pattern2="added" (sum of all cells matching "added" would be too high, including the target values for cells matching "newly added", which would be a logical error)

Answer (score 0):

In case others may find this useful: I found that by adding an initial empty cell to my list of search terms, a zero value will be returned instead of error.

```
={INDEX(SearchTerms!$A$1:$A$38,MAX(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(SearchTerms!$A$1:$A$38,SearchCell)),0,1)*((SearchTerms!$B$1:$B$38)+1)))}
```

NB: Column A has the search terms, B is the row number index.