# Search for multiple strings (in subsequent rows of a named range) in a string in Excel using Functions

Tags: excel, search

I have a long list of records and need a flag, per record as to whether one column contains one of a list of values.

```
A          B                C
ID   |    REF     |     DESCRIPTION     |   
1    |  DFGF7F    | a long text string  |
2    |  8DFGFG    | a long text string  |
3    |  SDIUFD    | a long text string  |
4    |  DF7G7F    | a long text string  |
5    |  F7G78F    | a long text string  |
```

elsewhere:

```
REF STRINGS
A123
B234
C345
```

I need to a formula for each record in column D that returns 1 / 0 if one of the REF STRINGS is found in column C?

I found one close match at [ [Excel: Search for a list of strings within a particular string using array formulas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313919/excel-search-for-a-list-of-strings-within-a-particular-string-using-array-formu) ] but it only worked on one row and didn't do what I wanted (it returned a string of one of the REF STRINGS), plus I didn't understand how the function broke down, so couldn't tweak it.

Comment: Have a look at the second function in the answer (returning row number) - and enter it as an array formula - it's pretty much what you want.

Comment: Found out the reason it wasn't working, after I entered it as an array formula (Ctrl Shft Enter), I'd edit the formula and just hit Enter, returning it to a normal function. Thanks for making me re-visit it. ; )

Answer (score 0):

See if this formula works for you:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(B1,C1,1)),0,1)
```

where the 0 means false and the 1 means true at the end of the formula.
This checks to see if the content in B1 is in C1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the problem here is more complex than that, because he wants to to check if there is a value out of a list of values inside a string - so it's more like FIND(B1:B20,C1,1) - this is not quite the same ;)