# Excel: Search for many text strings in a cell, and return all positive results

Tags: excel

I need a function that will search a cell for many keyword text strings (model numbers) and return each model number that it finds.  In all my research I have only found solutions that provide one matching keyword, but I would like *all* matching keywords.

An example of a solution only finding one keyword: [Excel: Search for a list of strings within a particular string using array formulas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313919/excel-search-for-a-list-of-strings-within-a-particular-string-using-array-formu)

Example of what I would like:

**Cell to search in (A1) contains:**

A-007858 CustomerCompanyName D1001, S1135, BE60 and R235 New 6 and 8 Packs

**Search Keywords (on separate worksheet A1-A70):**

A32: D1001

A43: S1135

A6: BE60

A64: R235

**Desired Output:**
Each model number found (D1001, S1135, BE60, R235) displayed in cells B1, C1, D1, and E1 next to the cell that was searched (A1).  The order of the model numbers is not important.  I would prefer an Excel function solution rather than VBA.

Comment: How many cells contain the text to be searched?  Only A1 or A1:A???

Comment: Several thousand cells contain text to be searched

Comment: Then you will probably want VBa. The array formula will bog down excel with that many formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula in B1 and copy over:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$70,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$70)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$70,$A1))),COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

Replace `Sheet2` with the name of the sheet on which your list resides.

It will be in order of the list on the other sheet.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott!  I wouldn't have figured that out on my own, but now I understand the logic behind your formula.

Comment: Also, the formula doesn't seem to be slowing down my machine too considerably.  I am running with quite a bit of RAM.  But, if you wanted to provide a VBA solution I wouldn't be upset :)

Comment: I am of the opinion that if a formula works and is acceptable in overhead, why reinvent the wheel.  If you want to try it feel free.  I would load both lists into arrays with a third array for output.  Then cycle first through the list of sentences then through the list of lookups using instr to test.  Then load a two dimensional array with those that match.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many keywords you can do this fairly simply:

```
B1 = IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("D1001",A1)),"","D1001")
```

where you can replace "D1001" with a reference to the cell in the other sheet. C1:E1 would be analogous.

If you have a lot, then you'll need something more involved like @ScottCraner suggests.

Comment: Thanks Alexis!  Yes, I had considered that solution, but I am searching for 70+ keywords so it would get pretty cumbersome.  Thank you for your input though