# Formula to create grid from list in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have data in two columns (`H2:I8`) and I need to be able to work through that data and assign values within a grid (`B1:E5`).

[image]

As you can see, there are multiple values in the first row, so using the formulas `INDEX` and `MATCH` is where I started.  To get to the next level, I used this formula:

```
{=IF(INDEX($I$2:$I$8,SMALL(IF($B2=$H$2:$H$8,ROW($H$2:$H$8)-ROW($H$2)+1),COLUMN(A1)))=C$1,"YES","NO")}
```

-- Don't worry about the `#NUM!` for now.

The trouble is that the `SMALL` function only contains the values that match, so `CHECK 3` appears in `D3` and I actually want it in `E3` (and obviously I would change this to a `YES`), whereas `D3` should be a `NO`.

But I don't know how to do it...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as an array `{=SUM(IF($C2=$H$2:$H$8,1,0)*IF(D$1=$I$2:$I$8,1,0))}`

It gives a sum of the counts. I assume you can change the 1=true, 0=false value to the results you require afterwards

Comment: It was very close, just a couple of cell references, but this is exactly what I was after!  Thanks Bryan.  This was the completed entry:

=IF(SUM(IF($B2=$H$2:$H$8,1,0)*IF(C$1=$I$2:$I$8,1,0))=1,"YES","NO")

Comment: Just a little warning. With the sum, if you have an exact answer twice, you will get a 2. Your if will then fail, and the answer will be no. I recommend using a `>=1` instead of `=1`

Comment: Good point Bryan.  BTW - If C$1 needed to be a wildcard match ("heck" instead of "check"), does Excel copy with an IF within a range?

Comment: you can use something like `=IF(IFERROR(FIND(L12,M12),FALSE),TRUE,FALSE)` but be warned, it does have issues as well, such as not recognizing that `Heck` is in `Check`

Comment: I think I was not very clear in what I was asking. If the value was a substring in a cell, FIND doesn't seem to match the range.  For example, if I3 was "aaCheck2", am I able to search for that within I2:I8 and get a "YES" in D2?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313919/excel-search-for-a-list-of-strings-within-a-particular-string-using-array-formu`

Might help