# Reverse Index Match Keyword

Tags: excel, excel-formula, keyword

I have a large spreadsheet of keywords and need to group them by their root terms. Each of the keywords contains the root term in the phrase with a geography or other term attached (e.g. tree removal boston with root term being tree removal).

I have a column with all the keywords (~30,000) in column B and the list of 73 root terms in column Z. I want to compare the keywords in column B against the root terms in column Z and return the root term into column C.

I have tried a few array formulas, index/match, vlookup, etc. with no avail.

Comment: You could use the `Instr()` function. However you would then have to loop over all 73 root terms, or use 73 helper columns to determine if the root term is in the string. Calling 30K * 73 instr formula's would be a huge burden on your application. A VBA solution would be the best in this case. Here is some info on `instr()` https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php

Comment: Not exactly a "duplicate" question, but the answer on this question has the functionality you need I think?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313919/excel-search-for-a-list-of-strings-within-a-particular-string-using-array-formu

Answer (score 0):

If all the "root terms" will be the first word in the "Keyword" then the below will match it for you. I will assume your list of keywords starts in cell B1, and this formula will be entered into cell C1.

```
{=INDEX($Z$1:$Z$73,MATCH(1,SEARCH($Z$1:$Z$73,B1,1),0))}
```

This is an array formula, so needs to be entered with `Shift + Ctrl + Enter`. If the position of the root term isn't the first word, I will need to think a bit longer.

Comment: Thanks - Ill try that - the root term is the first word in all cases.

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept this answer if it does in fact answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in C1:

```
=INDEX($Z$1:$Z$73,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($Z$1:$Z$73,B1)),-1,1)*ROW($Z$1:$Z$73)))
```

Array Formula press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> at the same time
Wherever the position of the root is it will find it