# Excel Function checking street name in full addresses

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, countif

I have two sheets in excel, on containing full addresses and one containing street names. I need to create a lookup function that checks each full address to see if it contains one of the street names in the other sheet.

Normally i would use this =VLOOKUP or =Countif function to return a value if the cell exist in the lookup matrix, but they both check the whole content of the cell. while i only need to see if it contains a specific part.

Example cells would be.

Full Adresse Sheet1 A1:

Alpha street 34, fictional city Zip230

Lookup Sheet2 columns A:

Alpha Street

Beta Street

...

trying to create a function that check if any string in Column A Sheet2 exisit inside the string in Sheet1 A1. Even better if the function is not case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

If found this stackoverflow question that might be helpful:

[Excel: Search for a list of strings within a particular string using array formulas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313919/excel-search-for-a-list-of-strings-within-a-particular-string-using-array-formu)

Tweaking the array formula provided in the answer, I think you could try something like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(streetLookup!$B$1:$B$7,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(streetLookup!$B$1:$B$7,A1)),-1,1)*(ROW(streetLookup!$B$1:$B$7)-ROW(streetLookup!$B$1)+1))),"")
```

A few notes:

- The formula assumes the addresses are in column A and that there's a sheet named "streetLookup".
- For the lookup sheet I put the street names in column B only so that it's a little more clear in the above formula what sheet each range refers to.
- I don't have a ton of experience with array formulas, but after playing around with this I noticed that I had to use a defined range (i.e. couldn't just use the entire column). I think it's because the formula will not work as expected if there are any empty cells within the range.
- Since this is an array formula, remember to use ctrl+shift+enter

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards in `countif` formulas as well:

`=COUNTIF(rng,"*txt*")`

This will count all cells that contain the string `txt` anywhere in the desired range.

Comment: Hi Roe, this is sort of the reverse of what i need :) it shows me that a street name exit in X number of addresses. but i need to check if each address contain any of the streets.

Comment: have you looked into the sumproduct function.  There might be some posibility there for what you're needing.

Answer (score 0):

This formula should do the trick:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(search_range,lookup_cell)))>0
```

where `search_range` is the column where you have your street names, and `lookup_cell` is the cell that you are searching in that instance.

As far as I've tested it, this is not case-sensitive.