# Excel: Find and retrieve multiple terms from a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to retrieve all the terms from a list from a text in an excel  cell.

I have tried this before and it works! But it only gives me one term and I require to find all of them: [Excel: Search for a list of strings within a particular string using array formulas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313919/excel-search-for-a-list-of-strings-within-a-particular-string-using-array-formu)

this is the code I am currently using:

List of words to search for: G1:G7

Cell to search in: A1

```
 =INDEX(G1:G7,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(G1:G7,A1)),-1,1)*(ROW(G1:G7)-ROW(G1)+1)))
```

I would love to have an array of terms separated by a comma, if possible:

term 1, term 2, term 3, term 4, etc.

Comment: Please show an example of your data, and what you would like as a result. Although many post screenshots, they can be difficult to work with. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook that demonstrates the problem (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question

Comment: Sure thing @RonRosenfeld and Sujay:

This is the formula with which I started with...
![Image one](https://i.imgur.com/f77FMZI.png)

This is the new one:
![Image 2](https://i.imgur.com/cqWXIg7.png)

And this is how the list of terms look like in the other tab:
![List 1](https://i.imgur.com/vptcovn.png)
![List 2](https://i.imgur.com/pu82wb9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of Excel has the `TEXTJOIN` function, you may be able to use this **array** formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(INDEX(searchWords,N(IF(1,1/(ISNUMBER(FIND(" "&searchWords&" "," "&A1&" ")))*ROW(searchWords)))),""))
```

where `searchWords` refers to your list of words in `G1:G7`

**Notes:**

- Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar
- This depends on `searchWords` being a single word, and being separated, in A1, by <kbd>space</kbd>'s.  If there is punctuation, you will need to use nested `SUBSTITUTE` functions to replace the punctuation with spaces.
- if the above is not the case, then a VBA solution will be simpler.

Comment: My excel does not have the TEXTJOIN function, I am using google spreadsheets now, but I think I am doing something wrong, I am not getting the expected result. I'll try to be more specific about my current layout. I have a tab called "List of values", that has a list of terms, from cell 1 to 390. On the other tab I have a cell with an array of 5 terms, but only 3 of those terms are part of the list on the "List of values" tab. The result that I get with the first formula is only one term, I have tried the formula you proposed, but I am getting nothing at all. :S

Comment: @Ernesto Working with screenshots is difficult.  Since that is all you have chosen to provide, I won't be able to help you at this point. If no one else provides a solution, consider providing data in a useful form as I suggested in my comment to your question above. Be sure your data includes enough to be able to reproduce what you require.

Comment: Would it make it easier to share the actual Google Spreadsheet, Ron? Can I share it here?

Comment: @Ernesto As I wrote in my comment to your question, you can post a link to a workbook.

Comment: I see... thanks Ron, this would be it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LU6C0FHb8p2xV0bILzOYtmgKnY2VKBsioynoYH77y1Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ernesto It may be that the `INDEX` function in **Sheets** cannot be tweaked, as in **Excel**, to return an array of non-contiguous values. You'll need to check with a **Sheets** expert.  If that is the case, or if you want to do this in your Excel sans `TEXTJOIN`, a VBA macro would be the best approach.

Comment: I see... I'll try to find a more up-to-date version of Excel tomorrow and try, thank you so much Ron! I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186333/discussion-between-ernesto-and-ron-rosenfeld).