# Excel Find/Search Function Returning False Negatives

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This simple issue has me absolutely stumped. I'm trying to search a single cell for a list of items, and for some reason it is only working part of the time.

[image]

Columns A:C are all formatted as Text, and there are no trailing/leading spaces in Column A.

Replacing `search` with `find` returns the same thing, as does using a named range instead of `A2:A4`.

Searching for a single/specific item (`=SEARCH($A$3,B5)`) works just fine.

Comment: See [this](https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-one-of-many-things). Note you are actually trying to compare a list (read: array) of values.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8313919/1578604

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula is returning an array of values, which you can see if you use the Formula Evaluation tool on the Formula bar. On the worksheet, you will see only the first array element.

Spread out, the return looks like:

[image]

Note that you only see the "number" if it is first in the array (eg `Yellow`)

If all you want is a TRUE/FALSE answer, then you need to remove the errors and `OR` the result:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:A$4,B2)))
```

This is an array formula. In some versions of Excel you may need to  enter/confirm an **array formula** by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

[image]

If you want something else, please clarify.

**Edit:**  OP has now clarified that what he really wants is to return the color.
Assuming there is only a single color to be returned, the following will return the first color:

```
    =IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:A$4,B2)))*ROW($A$2:$A$4),1)),"")
```

[image]

In the case where there are multiple colors, and you want to return them all, it would be best if you have Excel 2016+ with the `TEXTJOIN` function.  If you do, you can use something like:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$2:A$4,B2)))*ROW($A$2:$A$4),{1,2,3})),""))
```

In the formula above, the array constant `{1,2,3}` refers to the number of possible entries in `find_text`.  If this number is much more than three, or will vary, replace the array constant with a formula to generate the relevant array.

One such formula might be:

```
ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROWS(find_text)))
```

The entire formula might then be:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(find_text,B2)))*ROW(find_text),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROWS(find_text))))),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, converting to an array formula updates everything to work consistently and as you'd expect, but ultimately I need to be able to search each cell in Column B for any value in A, then return the found string. If the formula will only return a value when the first item is found, that obviously won't work. How can the formula be adapted for this? (I hope this isn't deviating too much from the original question)

Comment: @Tock I've added a formula that should do what you say you want.  In the future, please ask for what you really want, rather than something else that is only a partial description. You might search for XY problem to better understand that issue.

Answer (score 0):

1] Find_text position

In `C2`, formula copied down :

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH(A$2:A$4,B2))
```

2] Find_text result

In `D2`, formula copied down :

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,SEARCH(A$2:A$4,B2),A$2:A$4)
```

[image]

Comment: Worth noting that this will find the last matched text in case multiple texts have been found in the sentence.

Comment: Also, while your answer gives a possible solution to the original problem, it doesn't explain the observed behaviour of the issues encountered.