# Look for a value from a list in a text string - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a column of data with comments containing, among other things, the product number I need for a different column. I have figured out a way to get the data, but I would have to pull out each and every product number, which would be the nested If statement to end all If statements. I have all the product numbers in a list, but I can't figure out how to search the string (Column K) for a value from the list(Products tab, column B).

The first string contains the product number "C21" I have tried:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("C21",K5)), "C21", "Nope")
```

This is what I've got that will return the value, but again, I'd have to individually call out every product and I just can't.

Also tried

```
=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(Products!$B$2:$B$500,K5,1),Products!$B$2:$B$500)
```

Where `K5` has the text string and column B on the tab Products has my list. Returns a value of 0, despite the product being on the list and in the comment

Also tried

```
=INDEX(Products!B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(Products!$B$2:$B$200)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Products!$B$2:$B$200,K5))),1))
```

Also returns a value of 0

Data samples:

What I need

Product#---------Comments:

_______-----------C21 at Packers Falls S/S

_______----------3891DX32 (Already Open)

[image: Modified spreadsheet]

Then on the Product Tab:

Product

A373

B307

C21

D3135

E3176

G363

L367

[image: Product List]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel: Search for a list of strings within a particular string using array formulas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30914656/9606612)

Comment: It is difficult to follow, please try first to explain the problem and the data, then what you have tried. For the input and expected output, put the data in table markdown format, so it is easier to copy and reproduce it (no need to share screenshots). You can use the following tool: [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) copy the content of your excel there, then Generate->Copy to Clipboard and finally to your question.